# error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed)

Tags: python, list, image, opencv, error-handling

I have a list of gray-sclaed images. I read them in with this code:

```
import glob
import cv2


folders = glob.glob(r'path\to\images\*')
imagenames_list = []
for folder in folders:
    for f in glob.glob(folder+'/*.png'):
        imagenames_list.append(f)

read_images = []        

for image in imagenames_list:
    read_images.append(cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE))
```

Now, I am trying to resize all the images in `read_images` with this function:

```
def resize_images(img, new_width, new_height):
    size = (new_width, new_height)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img, size)
    return resized_img
```

I applied the function as follows:

```
resized_img = [resize_images(img, new_width=128, new_height=32) for img in read_images]
```

And Python returned this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-9352534280fd> in <module>
      1 #Anwenden der Funktion auf die Liste col_image
----> 2 resized_img = [resize_images(img, new_width=128, new_height=32) for img in read_images]

<ipython-input-21-9352534280fd> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 #Anwenden der Funktion auf die Liste col_image
----> 2 resized_img = [resize_images(img, new_width=128, new_height=32) for img in read_images]

<ipython-input-20-e4d9e7d9b2fa> in resize_images(img, new_width, new_height)
      2 def resize_images(img, new_width, new_height):
      3     size = (new_width, new_height)
----> 4     resized_img = cv2.resize(img, size)
      5     return resized_img

error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4045: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Can someone help?
What further information do you need? I already applied this function to a list of a smaller number of images (around 650 images) and it worked. Now, this list contains more than 180k images. Furthermore, the images' sizes are different, but they also were different for the other 650 images.

Comment: Can you run the loop and add `print(size)` to your `resize_images` function? What does it print?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I changed the code to `import cv2
def resize_images(img, new_width, new_height):
    size = (new_width, new_height)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img, size)
    print(size)
    return resized_img`. Now, it prints (128, 32) multiple times until it stops at a certain point and I got the same error again.

Comment: I see. What does the image where it breaks look like? Try to also print the image `shape`. `print(img.shape)`.

Comment: Ok, I also let the function print the img.shape. Now I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'`. Seems like there is a NoneType object anywhere. How do I identify where it is?

Comment: Ok, so here is what I think is happening. When you load your images from the files, some of them probably aren't images. You when you run your `cv2.imread(image, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)` on those files, it returns `None`. I would suggest you `print(f)` and see if everything is in order.

Comment: Ok, I did that. But how can I check this? Should I check the ends of the filenames or what do you think about? I only uploaded png-files, so only images..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in order to find where it is going wrong. Hopefully it will tell you which file crashes the loop.

```
import glob
import cv2
from cv2 import error


def resize_images(img_, new_width, new_height):
    size = (new_width, new_height)
    resized_img_ = cv2.resize(img_, size)
    return resized_img_


folders = glob.glob(r'path\to\images\*')
img_names_list = []
read_imgs = []
resized_imgs = []
for folder in folders:
    for file in (glob.glob(folder+'/*.png')):
        img_names_list.append(file)
        img = cv2.imread(file, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
        read_imgs.append(img)
        try:
            resized_img = resize_images(img, new_width=128, new_height=32)
            resized_imgs.append(resized_img)
            # print(file, img, resized_img)
        except error as err:
            print(f'{file} returns {img}. Resize does not work')
            print(err)
```

Comment: That's great! It works out perfectly! Would you just delete this image? As the error code suggested, there is no image available regarding the file path...

Comment: So you're saying it returns a filepath to an image that doesn't exist? Or just to an image that is corrupt in some way? In the second case, it really depends on you if you want to keep it. If yes, you should see if you can replace it with a non-corrupt version somehow. However I cannot tell you what to do with your files.

Comment: Ok, perfect! It returns a file path to an image which is corrupt. So, I think the best way is to delet this file. You helped me a lot! Thank you! :)